# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: swift, xcode

I got an error,
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)  .
Error is
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxJTT.png)

Traceback is

```
2017-06-11 22:10:04.009 Kenshin_Swift[6073:541383] Unknown class PhotoController in Interface Builder file.
2017-06-11 22:10:04.120 Kenshin_Swift[6073:541383] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fe830f06900> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PhotoSelect.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001068efd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010635821e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001068efc99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000105c919df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000106eae293 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010712279e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001068949e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107121122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000106eb49c5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106eb52e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106eb561c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106eb5e70 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106f144f3 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 483
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000106f13935 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000106f0f7f6 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 365
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000106f0f678 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 234
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000106dcd239 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 90
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000106f09c14 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 354
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106f0ad8e -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 206
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000106ebb96f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 692
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000106ebc07f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 147
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106ebd873 -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 507
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000106dc3a87 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 621
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000106dd485b -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 451
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000106dc30d7 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 838
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000106d7f7bf -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 849
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000106d7fc06 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000106d93519 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000106d0bf8d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000106d120ed -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000106d0f26d -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    31  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a55d6cb __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a55d544 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a55d8cd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106894761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010687998c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106878e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106878884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    38  UIKit                               0x0000000106d0daea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    39  UIKit                               0x0000000106d13c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    40  Kenshin_Swift                       0x0000000105b9f07f main + 111
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109dc368d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

PhotoController is

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class PhotoController:UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func PhotoSelect(_ sender: Any) {
            }

    @IBAction func PhotoSend(_ sender: Any) {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])

    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //myImageUploadRequest()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



  }
```

Outlet is 
[outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N834E.png)

I read why this error message happen.  It said when "Outlet" is wrong,this error happen.But I do not know how to fix this.I saw outlet of PhotoSelect&PhotoSend has !,but I cannot understand this mean.What should I do?

Comment: Does this error occur on build, or when you select an image?  If on build, delete and then reconnect you imageView outlet in Interface Builder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the two outlets `PhotoSelect` and `PhotoSend`. You probably accidentally created these as `@IBOutlet`, deleted them and recreated them as `@IBAction`.

See how they have a `!` next to them. This means that these outlets are no longer connected. So when you run you app, your storyboard cannot find those outlets in your view controller, so it crashes.

You need to remove those outlets by clicking the `x`.